# Command.Start() Causes Program To Hang

Tags: windows, go, cmd, exec, freeze

I'm trying to open a new application, and then close the current application. I read that `Command.Start()` doesn't wait for the command to finish, but my program doesn't exit until fgl-updater.exe exits as well. I need it to close so that I can remove/replace it with the updated version.

```
func RunUpdater() {
    wd, _ := os.Getwd()
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/c", "start", wd+"/fgl-updater.exe")
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: ", err)
    }

    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Is this a Windows/cmd issue?

Comment: Shouldn't it read `cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/c start " + wd + "/fgl-updater.exe")`?

Comment: I honestly don't know. What I have opens the new Window, it just doesn't allow the original window to close.

Comment: Hm... maybe `cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C start /B " + wd + "/fgl-updater.exe")` helps (note the `/B`)? Anyway, I don't really understand why you need `cmd /C start` at all; perhaps just using `cmd := exec.Command(wd + "/fgl-updater.exe")` is enough?

Comment: I need it to open in a new window, and that's (apparently) what that command does. I'll try your suggestion though.